# How to use Linux to read a file line by line and add each line with a ' 1' in the end?

Tags: linux, shell

I've got a txt file (size from 10M to 1G) like:

```
1 2
2 3
4 5
5 6
7 6
1 9
...
```

And I need to make into

```
1 2 1
2 3 1
4 5 1
5 6 1
7 6 1
1 9 1
...
```

what command should I use? How long it takes? I am using a Mac. I guess it is the same as Linux?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '$0=$0" 1"' file
1 2 1
2 3 1
4 5 1
5 6 1
7 6 1
1 9 1
```

It adds `" 1"` to `$0`, which contains the full line. Then it prints everythings as the default awk action is `{print $0}`.

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/$/ 1/' file
1 2 1
2 3 1
4 5 1
5 6 1
7 6 1
1 9 1
```

It replaces every `$` (end of line) with `" 1"`, so that it finally appends `" 1"` to every line.

> How long it takes?

It should be pretty fast. To quantify it, append `time` before your command:

```
$ time awk ...
```

Comment: Nice! I don't know why I tend to use `g` always. Updated, thanks :)

Comment: I tried 
    $ awk '$0=$0" 1"' file > newfile
but it gives an extra space before the '1'. Why was it? I am rather new to Linux, and I wish to get some more help! Thx!

Comment: Do you have any space after your last column? Note that `$0=$0" 1"` appends exactly ` 1` to the line.

Comment: fixed! I used
$ awk '$0=$0"1"' file>newfile

Answer (score 2):

with sed, replace the end of each line with the addtional text:

```
sed 's/$/ 1/' file
```

If you need to save the modifications back to the original file, use

```
sed -i 's/$/ 1/' file
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first and it worked, as it showed the changed file on screen. But the second one doesn't work... Error is: sed: 1: "test": undefined label 'est'. But I used test, not est. Don't know what is wrong..

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all. what command were you running when you got that error?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $0,1}' file
```

would do it.

Comment: Seems it adds two spaces in between... or I did something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @user2579376 no it won't add two spaces.